# unable to set focus on textboxes using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set focus on textboxes 1 by 1 on tab press but its not working for me.

here is code that i have tried:

```
function showstep2() {
    document.getElementById('step2').style.visibility = 'visible'
    document.getElementById('prevOrdQuan').focus();
}

function showstep3() {
    document.getElementById('step3').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('takeOutAmt').focus();
}    

function showstep4() {
    document.getElementById('step4').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('compsPerWeek').focus();
}
```

HTML:

```
<table style="width: 100%;" align="left">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>How many TakeOut Orders do You do each week?</td>
            <td><input tabindex="1" type="text" name="prevOrdQuan" id="prevOrdQuan" size="6" value="7" onblur=" doCalc1(); showstep2();"  /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table id="step2"  style="width: 100%;  visibility: hidden;"  align="left">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>How many NEW TakeOut Orders do You expect each week? (15% Expected)</td>
            <td><input tabindex="2" type="text" name="newOrdQuan" id="newOrdQuan" size="6" value="7" onblur="doCalc(); showstep3();" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table id="step3" style="width: 100%; visibility: hidden;" align="left">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>How Much Is Your Average Takeout Order?</td>
            <td><input tabindex="3" type="text" name="takeOutAmt" id="takeOutAmt" size="6" value="20" onblur="doCalc2(); showstep4();" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

There are 3 textboxes,for 1st textbox i have set focus on load like this:

```
 function setFocus() {
    document.getElementById("prevOrdQuan").focus();
}
```

It sets the focus for 1st textbox.after pressing tab on 1st textbox it displays 2nd textbox but focus is not set on second  textbox.

This is only the problem that i need to resolve.

Comment: where is your `showstep3()` ?

Comment: can you create a [jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @ABFORCE i don't know how to create jsfiddle..

Comment: @neha it is pretty simple! copy/paste your code into related fields in jsfiddle home page then click **save** then give us it's link in your browser address bar!

Comment: there's a big button that says `Save` and jsfiddle will redirect to a saved version of fiddle, copy web address and post it here. easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in the `showstep2` function, you are focussing the element with the id `prevOrdQuan` which is the first text box. I think you wanted to focus `newOrdQuan`.

So change

```
document.getElementById('prevOrdQuan').focus();
```

to

```
document.getElementById('newOrdQuan').focus();
```

And it should work.

**EDIT**

You also need anything focusable below your text boxes (an additional input etc). Otherwise if you press tab on the first (and only) textbox, the browser focusses the address bar and thus firing the onblur event on both next textboxes and displaying both at the same time.
Here is an example of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/24TK4/1/

**2nd EDIT**

I think this is an elegant solution of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/24TK4/2/

Look at the link at the and of the HTML code, it just displays an invisible link.

Comment: then it display next 2 textboxes at once.

Comment: its working only if we added   <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">&nbsp;</a>...why?

Comment: When you add the link, the browser has to focus something after the first text box and thus the focus remains on the page (focusses the invisible link for a moment until the onblur script has been executed) and does not switch to the address bar.

Comment: yes you are right..this small thing realy frustrated me from 3-4 hours.thanks for your help.

Comment: are you there.i get one problem here??